# Cannot access microsoft and symantec sites AND I am not infected with conficker

Tags: windows, website, malware

I cannot access microsoft and symantec sites (at least) and I have run the microsoft removal tool and sophos removeal tool for conficker as well as visited 
[Conficker Eye Chart](http://www.confickerworkinggroup.org/infection_test/cfeyechart.html)
which displays all the images. Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

EDIT: I found the solution but not the exact cause. The solution was to download Windows security essentials after seeing many people here suggesting it as a good free AV solution. The cause was a malware but since I discovered 4 of them I dont know which one caused this behaviour. None of them was CONFICKER though

Comment: What happens when you try to access these sites ?

Comment: Maybe you are infected with something else. We need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Conficker is not the only malware capable of blocking sites. Many skid ready malware (RATS) allow the user to block sites by editing the host files.

Take a look at them on your system and see if anything looks out of the order....You may be still infected with the malware I recommend scanning you computer with [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) to make sure your system is clean.

Comment: Malware Bytes is an excellent malware-removal tool - it's a standard part of my toolkit. Most of the "FakeAV" malwares also block websites.

Answer (score 0):

What IP gives command "ping www.microsoft.com" and "ping www.symantec.com" 
Can you check your hosts file ? what is in it ?

You did not tell your OS - but for latest windows you can use this guide http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/edit-hosts-file-in-windows-7-windows-vista/